# HTTP Post request handler in java

Tags: java, http, post, request, handler

I hope someone will be able to help me understand how to create an endpoint HTTP server listener. I'm trying to create a POST request handler that can save all post requests made to a text file.

The purpose is for a Game state integration between My application and Counter-Strike. Ive read their documentation ([csgo GSI documentation](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Counter-Strike:_Global_Offensive_Game_State_Integration)) and the example given in here is almost exactly what I'm looking for. But its written in nodejs and I will need it to work with Java.

I have only been able to create a HTTPServer but can't seem to understand how I can create a POST request handler which records the data sent to "data" request.

How can I create a handler which can record all requests sent to data?

Comment: The easiest way is to use Spring Boot Rest. https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the easiest & fastest way is to grab a SpringBoot app from https://start.spring.io/ (add `Web` dependency). And then create a Spring `@RestController` like that:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/cs")
public class CsController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void processCsData(@RequestBody CsData csData) {
        processCsData(csData);
    }

}
```

where `CsData` is a POJO class that they send to you. `processCsData()` is your method to do whatever you like with the data.

Now you need to host it somewhere so that it would be reachable from the Internet or you can use https://ngrok.com/ to create a tunnel for test purposes.